# Unexpected behavior of boolean operators

Tags: sql, boolean, bit-manipulation

Why many languages (as far as I could check) process conditional and bitwise boolean operators in order `and` then `or` (as usual), but MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL don't?

JavaScript

```
a = true || true && true && false;         // true
a = true | true & true & false;            // 1
a = 1 | 1 & 1 & 0;                         // 1
```

Java

```
a = true || true && true && false;         // true
a = true | true & true & false;            // true 
a = 1 | 1 & 1 & 0;                         // 1
```

Python

```
a = True or True and True and False        // true
a = 1 | 1 & 1 & 0                          // 1
```

Delphi

```
a := true or true and true and false;      // true
a := 1 or 1 and 1 and 0;                   // 1
```

PHP

```
$a = true | true & true & false;           // 1
$a = true || true && true && false;        // 1
```

c (gcc under CentOS)

```
a = true || true && true && false;         // true
a = true | true & true & false;            // true
a = 1 || 1 && 1 && 0;                      // 1
a = 1 | 1 & 1 & 0;                         // 1
```

MySQL

```
select 1 | 1 & 1 & 0 a                     -- 1
select true | true & true & false          -- 1
select true || true && true && false       -- 1
```

SQL Server

```
select 1 | 1 & 1 & 0 a                     -- 0 !
select cast(1 as bit) | cast(1 as bit) &
       cast(1 as bit) & cast(0 as bit)     -- 0 !
```

PostgreSQL

```
select true or true and true and false a   -- true
select 1 | 1 & 1 & 0 a                     -- 0 !
select 1::bit | 1::bit & 1::bit & 0::bit a -- 0 !
```

Comment: You should use parentheses in all languages so the intended order of evaluation is clear.

Comment: In the SQL Server example, you are using bitwise operators of equal precedence: [Operator Precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx). You probably meant to use [logical operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), for which `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are to be commended for doing your research, but I'm not sure how useful your tests in non-SQL languages are.  Do you understand how the expressions are parsed in the non-SQL languages?  Do you know how each DBMS treats the bitwise operators?  Are the `|` and `&` given equal precedence by the DBMS, perchance?  Well, MySQL doesn't seem to do that (it seems to treat `&` as higher precedence than `|`), but maybe PostgreSQL and SQL Server do.  AFAIK, the bitwise operators are not defined by the SQL standard, so referring to that is not much help.

Comment: @gordon-linoff, I know about parentheses, just doing some research about that strange behavior, because boolean logic was pretty much defined far before these languages and `&` has more priority than `|` (regardless it is boolean operation or bitwise). @jonathan-leffler - I just follow math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The | and & operators in SQL are [bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx), not logical operators. Bitwise | and & have equal [precedence in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx), in [MySQL & is higher than |](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html).

Logical operators in SQL are `and`, `or`, etc.

Comment: Thx @jakub-lortz, now it makes sense.